# Collapse nD numpy array into a 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to sum the values of a nD array along a particular axis to effectively collapse it into a 1D array.
I have been looking through the docs but haven't been able to find the right function. I will try to explain my question better with some code:

```
In [46]: g
Out[46]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

The output I need is:

```
array([5,10,15])
```

My actual data is a 7 MB file so I don't really want to use a for loop.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just doing

```
numpy.sum(g, axis=0)
```

should work.

Comment: aaah, I was looking at ma.compress and things.. way off. Thanks!